# One application is being run twice in tomcat7

Tags: java, tomcat7

I have deployed one war to tomcat7 webapps directory.

But when tomcat is starting it runs application twice.

What could cause this problem?

I have already met this case, but it was when I was mapping domain to webapp, but know all the configuration is standart, and there are two instances running.

Comment: In conf directory there is one context.xml which is unchanged - default

Answer (score 1):

This can happen if you have a symbolic link somewhere in your webapp directory, that points to a war file or exploded war directory. Tomcat simply follows those links and starts all application it finds.

Also check the configuration in `conf/server.xml` and make sure you haven't set up any other directories as `appBase`.

Comment: No symlinks :| I just have this line: INFO: Deploying web application archive /var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/my-webapp.war and then it is just starting twice. Maybe it is not related to tomcat, but it is hardly to imagine why it is happening.

Answer (score 0):

It might be possible that in your webapps directory you might have another war or another webapp already present.

Comment: webapps directory contains - /host-manager/, /my-webapp/, /manager/, my-webapp.war. So there is only one war deployed.